# R - Shiny - convert checkboxInput to numeric

Tags: r, binary, numeric, shiny

I'm learning & developing a little shiny app. Awesome stuff!

I have a checkboxInput that returns true/false, I need to convert it to numeric 1/0 and use it in a formula inside a table. My real-life example is somewhat more convoluted, but I have extracted a stackoverflow-life example below. Help appreciated!

In the app below, the user first selects the checkboxInput to play, and then inputs a number in the left panel. The main panel displays a table of the input number, the output number (the square of the input in this example) and the "status" of the checkboxInput, which is either True or False.

I'd like to return 1 or 0 instead of True or False.

In real life, my left panel takes a list of numbers as well as True/False statements, from which a formula returns a number to be displayed in the table. The True/False statements are like dummy variables.

Here is the ui.R

```
# ui.R
library("shiny")
# Define UI for slider demo application
shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    # Title
    headerPanel("Input-Output Shiny App")
     ,
     # User Input in sidebar panel
     sidebarPanel(
      # Yes/No
      wellPanel(
        checkboxInput("play", "Do you want to play?", FALSE)
         , 
         conditionalPanel(
           condition="input.play==true"
          , 
          numericInput("myinput", "My Input:", 0)
         )#end conditionalPanel
       )#end wellPanel
    )# end sidebarPanel
    ,
    # Output in main panel
    # See output$myResults in server.R
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("myResults")
    )# end mainPanel
  )#end pageWithSidebar
)#end shinyUI
```

And here is the server.R

```
# server.R
library("shiny")
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    myFunction <- function(myinput)
      {
      # compute output
      myoutput <- myinput*myinput
      myoutput
      }
    # Show computed values
    output$myResults <- renderTable(
      {
        r1 <- c("My Input",input$myinput)
        r2 <- c("My Output",myFunction(input$myinput))
        r3 <- c("Are you playing?",input$play)
        myTable <- do.call(rbind, list(r1,r2,r3))
        myTable
      }
      , align = c("lcc")
      , include.rownames = FALSE
      , include.colnames = FALSE
      , sanitize.text.function = function(x) x
    )#end renderTable         
  }#end function(input,output)
)#end shinyServer
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `as.integer()` happens to convert Boolean values into integers in the way you describe. Could you just wrap your reference to `input$play` with that function?

Comment: You're right Jeff, as.integer(input$play) does it! I had earlier tried as.numeric(input$play) without success, but I must have done it wrong because it seems to work too. do you want to make it an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the modified line: __r3 <- c("Are you playing?",as.integer(input$play))# 1/0__ And here a vaguely related thing I just figured out:
__r3 <- c("Are you playing?",if(input$play){print("You bet I'll play!")}else{print("No waaay!")})__

Comment: Jeff, do you want to make your comment an answer so I can select it and "close" the topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as.integer` happens to convert `TRUE` and `FALSE` to 1 and 0, respectively.

More generally, you could use an `if` or `ifelse` function to accomplish this.

```
play <- TRUE # or FALSE
r3 <- ifelse(play, "You bet!", "No way!")
```